# Assimp doesn't read weights for specific bone of a mesh from .dae or .fbx file

Tags: animation, import, model, assimp

I am having a problem with importing animated model (.dae or .fbx). In debug mode on the picture below, assimp doesn't load weights for specific bone. I tried for 3 different models and error is the same.
This is the last [model](https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/fantasy/sketchfast-5-contest-prof-dr-armpit-rigged) I tried. If you could help me, I would be very thankful!

[screenshot of a debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW0M1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found where was the error. If there is someone, with the same problem, this post might help you.
I solved the problem by deleting assimp (I am not sure which version was that, but I cloned the repo from github a few months ago), and then I added newer version. After that I don't have a problem mentioned in my previous post. Now mWeights in mBones is populated with data, compared to screenshot I left in the question above.